# Test environment variables depending on configuration mode

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, configuration, environment-variables, karma-jasmine

I have 5 environment files:

```
environment.common.ts
environment.a.ts
environment.b.ts
environment.c.ts
environment.ts
```

I have modified my angular.json to this:

```
...
"projects": {
   "app": {
     ...
     "architect": {
        "build": {
           ...
           "configurations": {
              "a": {
                 "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                       "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                       "with": "src/environments/environment.a.ts"
                    }
                 ],
                 ...
              },
              // same for b and c
           }
        }
     }
   }
}
// plus all the other needed configurations which are irelevant with the question
```

When i run `ionic cordova build android --configuration a` the app uses the environment variables from `environment.common.ts` **plus** the ones from `environment.a.ts`

**QUESTION**

Is there any way to `ng test` if the corrent environment variables are called when I run `ionic cordova build android --configuration a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check the environment variables being used when you run ng test with configuration flag, that's not possible. But in case you want to run your test scripts with a particular environment variables then you could definitely do that. `ng test --configuration` is use to run spec files with particular set of environment variables.
Hope it answers your query.